# Disable font smoothing with C#

Tags: c#, fonts, smoothing

Is there a way to enable/disable the font smoothing in C#? I mean the one at Start -> Display and Performance Options -> Smooth Edges of Screen Font.

I need it for my custom OCR code and would like to enable it only while the program is running.

Comment: doesnt answer your question but related reading: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/27/10405554.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know it is possible if you create your own fonts carefully basing them on GDI log fonts. Don't have actual c# code for you, but I will mention that the Font Class has the ability to use a log font -- see the various FromLogFont related methods. You care, because using log fonts are the way to do this, as the following C++ Q&A show  [Changing font smoothing for my application alone and not the global windows font smoothing settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347873/changing-font-smoothing-for-my-application-alone-and-not-the-global-windows-font)